# How to execute a Scrapy request immediately and get the returned response in parse method?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

How to execute a Scrapy request immediately and get the returned response in `parse` method?

I need to get some information from another link and combine it with the current information I have from the original link (in `parse` method). Therefore, I need to be able to execute a `scrapy` request and get the returned response.

Comment: send data from first request to second request  as `meta=` and combine alldata in second request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ScrapyRT (scrapy real time)

https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/01/22/introducing-scrapyrt-an-api-for-scrapy-spiders/

See example http://localhost:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=foo&url=http://example.com/product/1

> ScrapyRT will schedule a request in Scrapy for the URL specified and use the ‘foo’ spider’s parse method as a callback. The data extracted from the page will be serialized into JSON and returned in the response body.